# Order of derivation

Tags: logic

Let us consider the following 3 propositions

1)          ($n$ is good) $\iff (x=y)$

2)          ($n$ is good) $\iff (x=z)$

3)          ($n$ is good) $\iff (x=y=z)$

It is clear that from 1,2 we can obtain 3.

My doubt is whether is it possible to obtain 1 from 2,3  or similarly 2 from 1,3?

$\iff$ stands for if and only if

= stands for standard equal to

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Put some quantifiers in there, this makes no sense.

Comment: @GitGud Is it okay now ?

Comment: Not really, what about quantification on $x,y,z$? And for all $n$ where? In $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @GitGud ofcourse, But instead of quantification just treat them as propositions or else universal quanitifier for all 3 propositions.

Comment: How did this get $5$ up votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify, let's replace your propositions (which we have no context for) with propositional variables.

$$G: n\text{ is good}$$
$$P: x = y$$
$$Q: x = z$$

Note that $x = y = z$ is equivalent to $P\land Q$.

Now we have

(1) $G\leftrightarrow P$

(2) $G\leftrightarrow Q$

(3) $G\leftrightarrow P\land Q$

We cannot conclude (1) from (2) and (3): Consider the case when $P$ is true but $G$ and $Q$ are false.